# Multiple Languages TTS Engine

Tags: c#, .net, windows, text-to-speech

I am looking for multiple languages `TTS` Engine for my `.Net` Application.

The languages i need to speech is

1. English
2. Russia
3. Korea
4. Japan
5. Thailand

Is there any free framework or SDK for my requirement?

Comment: Have you tried [Microsoft System.Speech Library](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Text-to-Speech-Converter-0ed77dd5). The previous link has a tutorial on it.

Comment: Speech engine is only for English?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: No.
The TTS for English are many.

Answer (score 1):

I will say there are many frameworks and not sure of free now, as the frame work with basic functionality will be free but with advance functionality may not..

Refer [Google TTS(Text To Speech)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69335/Fun-with-Google-Text-To-Speech-eBook-reader-using) project..

this link have code and details with some 27 language details that one can refer,

I am sure this will do :)